# Can't convert int32 to Gluint

Tags: swift, opengl-es, glkit

So in opengl es I am trying to pass my vertex data to the shader. To do this u am doing the following.

```
glgetuniformloaction() 
Glenablevertexattribarray()
```

The problem is that the first function returns a Glint (int32) and the second function wants that number but in Gluint (Uint32)

My problem is any trials to convert between the two have failed so far.  Anyone know a way to?

Comment: Uniform locations and vertex attribute locations are not the same thing. If it's a vertex attribute you're dealing with, you need to use `glGetAttribLocation()` to retrieve it.

Comment: how you deal with this in another language? simply speaking, it is hard to know, what do you mean by a 'conversion'. try to update your question. what do expect from the  'conversion' between Int32 and UInt32 ??